# Android wait for browser intent to finish

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm coding a payment method that redirect to a URL ( my server ) and save some info then go to bank page for pay price. but there is a problem

I want wait for browser intent to finish/cancel pay process. but it's finish **immediately** after start intent and i can't check with `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`.
i have a result just after `startActivityForResult()` called.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(******));
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

.
.
.

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)                
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 100)
        Log.w("web", "finish");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is not very likely to return with a result, as there is no way to specify at which point it should return. You should use a `WebView` instead and detect the specific URL that you consider the finish or cancel point.

You need to implement a `WebViewClient` and override [`public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) in order to detect navigation to an specific URL, like so:

```
class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.equals(FINISH_URL)) {
            // Finished, we return true to handle navigation ourselves
            return true;
        }

        // Keep navigating
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your `WebView` you need to call `setWebViewClient()`:

```
WebView webview = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webview.loadUrl("https://yourpaymenturl.com/");
```

Comment: thank you .... yes i can use WebView by this way. but i have another problem because local android markets banned me for using web view and they told me i should using external browsers ....

Comment: As I said, there's no way to specify where the browser should consider the transaction is finished. If your payment platform allows you to specify a URL to be redirected when payment is finished (usually this is used in web pages to return to your website) you could specify a URL that it's handled by your app. That being said, this would be a hack.

Comment: If the device is 6.0+ you could use App Links to make it transparent for the user. For older devices, they will probably see app chooser. See https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The browser does not send a result. ACTION_VIEW and ACTION_MAIN protocols do not work properly with startActivityForResult().

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

You should start a WebView and determine if the user finished by tracking the current url.

Comment: thank you but as i said in another answer, i cant use webview because of some privacy policies that came from local android markets